# How to Truncate text in DataTable in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am using DataTable in Rshiny app to display the content of the Dataframe. But one element of the dataframe is of text, can have characters more than 1000. When I am displaying the datatable it shows all the text. I want to truncate it to first 250 characters and when hover it should show the full text. How can I do that?

ui.r

```html
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("flatly"),
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width=0
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width=12,
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Data",DT::dataTableOutput("train_data",width = "100%")))
  )
  )
))
```

server.r

```html
output$train_data <- renderDataTable({
 if(is.null(camry_data$train_data)){return ()}
    DT::datatable(camry_data$train_data, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5,10)),class = "display")
  })
```

Answer (score 6):

I closely followed section 4.4 Column Rendering here with a few tweaks: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

Also, the `targets` parameter can be set to a vector of column indexes, e.g. `c(1,3,5)`

```
output$train_data <- renderDataTable({
 if(is.null(camry_data$train_data)){return ()}
    DT::datatable(camry_data$train_data, options = list(lengthMenu = c(5,10),
    columnDefs = list(list(
      targets = "_all",
      render = JS(
        "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
        "return type === 'display' && data != null && data.length > 30 ?",
        "'<span title=\"' + data + '\">' + data.substr(0, 30) + '...</span>' : data;",
        "}")
      ))),
      class = "display")
})
```